# Google Maps API not returning Pin Markers

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Google Maps API after working fine for a couple of years began behaving erratically about a month ago.

The code all works fine from my development machine (my localHost), across ALL browsers, no problem.

But up on the production server, when calling from a https domain (a server reverse proxied through nginx, using Cloudflare) I find the following behaviour:

a. On Chrome and Safari it just returns the default 'initMap' map, *not the found result or marker (pin).*

**b. Firefox, it all works fine.**

c. IE, it only works when you refresh the page, not navigating page to page.

Among things I've tried:

1. Clearing all cookies and files from the browser caches.
2. Changing settings on Cloudflare (various caching and Speed settings).

The basic code is as follows (deployed through freemarker so ignore those parts. The code does work, as I described above.

```
function initMap() {
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
zoom: 10,
center: {lat: 53.3280182, lng: -6.3743767}
});
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', function() {
geocodeAddress(geocoder, map);
});
}

function geocodeAddress(geocoder, resultsMap) {
var address = "${clientLocation}";
geocoder.geocode({'address': address}, function(results, status) {
if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
  resultsMap.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: resultsMap,
    position: results[0].geometry.location
  });
} 
});
}

src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=xxxx&callback=initMap"
    async defer>
```

EDIT:
In response to comment below:

1. I did actually have the following code in while testing (it was removed for production), and *it was not returning anything*. (Sorry I should have mentioned that.)

   alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
2. I was getting nothing in the Java console either. However prompted by the helpful comment made below I changed the warning level to 'verbose' and saw the following error.

   [Violation] Added non-passive event listener to a scroll-blocking 'touchmove' event. Consider marking event handler as 'passive' to make the page more responsive. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5745543795965952

Comment: Any errors reported in the Javascript console? Possibly try outputting the `status` returned by the Geocoder if it isn't "OK", currently it silently fails. Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue.

Comment: Thank you. This was hard to reproduce as it was only occurring on a production server. I added an edit to my question above based on your feedback. Anyway your helpful comment lead me to finding the problem - when I made the console warnings 'verbose', I saw that it was an issue with 'rocketLoader' on Cloudflare. If you'd like to provide an answer below I will accept it. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: At this point you are best answering it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

As per the comments above, I found the issue once I changed the error reporting in the Chrome Java console to 'verbose'.

The issue was with 'Rocket Loader' on Cloudflare.

Once I switched this off, the problem resolved.